# Banshee and the Invisibility Cloak

Tags: werewolv.es

This question assumes that when lynched the items stay on the one lynched.

So if a Banshee is lynched they are seen visiting from the Graveyard as established by und-006. Banshee is also unique that they are one of the only roles seen visiting from the graveyard.

An Invisibility Cloak hides the one visiting. So if a Banshee is lynched with an Invisibility Cloak on them will they be seen visiting from the Graveyard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess: **No**.

The Disruption Orb appears to affect a Banshee in the graveyard (see `dov-666`), so it seems logical to assume that other items with passive effects will also affect a dead Banshee.

Comment: Correct, the cloak doesn't care if they are alive or not.